# Routing is not working when clicked on anchor tag

Tags: angular

New to the angular and I am following one of angular tutorials. Right now learning routes. But I am stuck at one place. So basically when i click on customer name i want to route to orders component and display that component, however when i hover over customer name i can see the route (eg :orders/3)created at the bottom of the browser but when i click on it, it is not showing orders component.

I have Customers component with customer list child component in it.
I also have Orders component.

Code from **order-routing.module.ts** file where i am linking order component with the order/:id route.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { OrderComponent } from './order.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'orders/:id', component: OrderComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ], 
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class OrdersRoutingModule {

}
```

Coe from **customer-list.component.html** file where i am binding routing with cust.name

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th (click)="sort('name')">Name</th>
            <th (click)="sort('city')">City</th>
            <th (click)="sort('orderTotal')">Order Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr *ngFor="let cust of filteredCustomers">
        <td>
            <a [routerLink]="['/orders', cust.id]">
                {{ cust.name | capitalize }}
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>{{ cust.city }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.orderTotal | currency:currencyCode:'symbol'}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="filteredCustomers && filteredCustomers.length">
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            {{ customersOrderTotal | currency:currencyCode:'symbol'}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="!filteredCustomers || !filteredCustomers.length">
        <td colspan="4">No customers found</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have imported ordersModule and CustomerModule(which holds customer list child component) into **app.module.ts** module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CustomerModule } from './Customer/customer/customer.module';
import { SharedModule } from './Shared/shared.module';
import { OrdersModule } from './Orders/order/order.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CustomerModule,
    OrdersModule,
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Code from **app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [ { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/customers'},
{ path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/customers' }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

[This is the screenshot showing route created when i hover over one of customer name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYUaz.png)

I have gone through the code lot of times now but i am not sure what i am doing wrong, i have also gone through the tutorial that i am following but couldn't understand what is missing to get orders component shown.
I would really appreciate any help towards fixing this.
Let me know if any code is needed here to understand more.

Comment: Can you please also share `AppRoutingModule` route configuration?

Comment: @PankajParkar i have added AppRoutingModule code.

Comment: Any error in console you can see?

Comment: @PankajParkar No error in the console

Comment: Is it possible to share a stackblitz of problem statement?

Comment: have you tried `[queryParams]="{id: cust.id}"`. [ref](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#setting-and-handling-query-params-and-fragments)

Comment: @PankajParkar the code is just in the visual studio. i haven't added it anywhere like github which can be shared.

Comment: @kushsavani the problem is not with generating routes, so i am not sure how [queryParams]="{id: cust.id}" would work here, as attached in the screenshot if you see routes are getting generated properly.

Comment: You need to import your `OrdersRoutingModule` somewhere (with no lazy loading). If you need lazy loading, then you must add a route inside your AppRoutingModule routes array and use `loadChildren`.

Comment: did you properly put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in any HTML?

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude <router-outlet></router-outlet> is declared in app.component.ts.

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

Comment: If possible please create a stackblitz demo and also share your template

Comment: Your AppRoutingModule is redirecting everything to '/customer' and that is a problem. No other routing configuration seems to contain the 'customer' route. Share a stackblitz of the entire thing to ease debugging as @YogendraR rightly said

Comment: here is the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/github/nikjd-git/angular-projects?file=src/app/app.module.ts

it is giving an error though for some interface module not found which is not the case on my local.

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude you are right, everything was redirecting to /customer because of { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/customers' } declared in app routing module. i have commented that part and it is now redirecting to orders component. Thanks a lot for pointing out the problem.

Comment: Great that it got solved. But you need that line else you won't have "catch-all" route, so re-order the imports in modules of AppModule and it should now work. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current top-most `AppRoutingModule` has the following declaration of routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/customers'},
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/customers' }
];
```

This is where the problem is. You need to include the orders before the second generic wildcard route (`'**'`).

But as you are using a feature routing module, let the feature module appear before the `AppRoutingModule` in the module imports of `AppModule`. You know routing order matters.

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CustomerModule,
    OrdersModule,
    AppRoutingModule, // brought this down
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule
  ],
```

Comment: ohh i did not know about routing orders, thanks a ton for clarifying. I did the changes you suggested and it is now working as expected.